# ASP.NET MVC EF Stored Procedure Error: ORA-06550 identifier 'XXAAI_AFCD.XXAAI_MISSION_Insert' must be declared

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Using Visual Studio 2015 Community, EF 6, ASP.NET MVC 5, Oracle, and using a database-first approach.

I'm following the instructions here (http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/CRUD-using-stored-procedures.aspx) to use stored procedures for CUD operations. No matter what I do I get the same error when `SaveChanges` is called.

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
>   PLS-00201: identifier 'XXAAI_AFCD.XXAAI_MISSION_Insert' must be declared
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

That's for the insert operation. A similar error is thrown for updated and delete. Also It doesn't matter what I called my stored procedure, it throws the same error for `XXAAI_AFCD.XXAAI_MISSION_Insert`. I've tested the stored procedure, and it works.

Here is the code:

```
PROCEDURE XXAAI_MISSION_Insert (P_MISSION_NUMBER IN XXAAI_AFCD.XXAAI_MISSION.MIS_MISSION_NUMBER%TYPE, 
  P_MISSION_TAG IN XXAAI_AFCD.XXAAI_MISSION.MIS_MISSION_TAG%TYPE, 
  P_MISSION_DATE IN XXAAI_AFCD.XXAAI_MISSION.MIS_MISSION_DATE%TYPE, 
  P_UPLOAD_DATE IN XXAAI_AFCD.XXAAI_MISSION.MIS_UPLOAD_DATE%TYPE, 
  P_NOTES IN XXAAI_AFCD.XXAAI_MISSION.MIS_NOTES%TYPE, 
  P_ACTIVE IN XXAAI_AFCD.XXAAI_MISSION.MIS_ACTIVE%TYPE, 
  P_USER_ID IN XXAAI_AFCD.XXAAI_MISSION.ADDED_BY%TYPE)
  IS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO XXAAI_AFCD.XXAAI_MISSION (MIS_MISSION_ID
  ,MIS_MISSION_NUMBER
  ,MIS_MISSION_TAG
  ,MIS_MISSION_DATE
  ,MIS_UPLOAD_DATE
  ,MIS_NOTES
  ,MIS_ACTIVE
  ,DATE_ADDED
  ,ADDED_BY
  ,DATE_MODIFIED
  ,MODIFIED_BY)
  VALUES (XXAAI_AFCD.XXAAI_MISSION_SEQ.NEXTVAL
  ,P_MISSION_NUMBER
  ,P_MISSION_TAG
  ,P_MISSION_DATE
  ,P_UPLOAD_DATE
  ,P_NOTES
  ,P_ACTIVE
  ,SYSDATE
  ,P_USER_ID
  ,SYSDATE
  ,P_USER_ID
  );


  END XXAAI_MISSION_Insert;
```

I've tried renaming the stored procedure, using a package, and using a standalone procedure. I've also right click on the stored procedure in Visual Studio and chose privileges and gave all users `Execute`. I've also created the stored procedure using authentication identifier `DEFINER` and `CURRENT_USER`. It all ends up giving the exact same error.

Here is the controller code in the `Create` method.

```
db.XXAAI_MISSION.Add(xXAAI_MISSION);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The error happens on `SaveChangesAsync()`.

I also have the following code in my model `OnModelCreating` method.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<XXAAI_MISSION>().MapToStoredProcedures();
```

In the Mapping Details tab for my `model.edmx` file, I have selected my stored procedure for the Insert operation and mapped all the fields. I have tried both returning and not returning a value. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: I think there is no need for using a stored procedure for this. It's a simple insert

Comment: Yeah the actual stored procedure does some checks to make sure the user id and other values are accurate before attempting the insert. I took all that out until I get this working.